# Return to my separated activity by launcher

Tags: android

Apologize for my poor english first.

I have an activity separated from my process which taskAffinity was set to ="", let us call it X, and the main activity is A.

The question is, when I operate like this:

1.A -> HOME -> (something triggered) -> show X

If I finish X, it will return to HOME, thats what I want.

But if I act like this:

2.A -> (something triggered) -> show X -> HOME

I want to return to X by clicking the apk icon, not to A.

How to make it?_?

If I didn't set X to be separate, it will return to A in case 1.
If I set X taskAffinity="", then it won't return to X in case 2.

anybody know what I am talking about >_< ?

Comment: I don't get your example. What is (something triggered)?

Comment: I start a service when the apk was launched, and the service was set to listen to some incoming message from internet such as voice call/ video call. So whenever the service catch an incoming call, it will  start X

Comment: Instead of giving it blank affinity try giving it it's own package android:taskAffinity="com.you.service.found.message"

Comment: So when you click your APK icon in the Home Menu. In any scenario it should always open A.

Comment: No I don't want it open A, I want it open X when I press HOME key in X before, is it possible?  One bad method I imagine is to set a public flag to record if X exists. If true, then switch to X in A's onResume..:|

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to have a single icon for your application then you cannot set `taskAffinity=""` for one of the activities. This will give you 2 separate tasks and the user won't be able to return to one of them because he can't tell the difference.

It sounds to me like you should use activityA as a dispatcher. When "something triggers", you start activityA and put an extra in the `Intent` that you use to start activityA. This extra basically tells actvityA that it should start activityX. If I follow you correctly when activityA gets this `Intent` with the special extra, it should start ActivityX and then call `finish()`. If the user presses "back" while in activityX, he will return to the HOME screen (not to activityA).